# terraform create phantom aws resource configuration to only use the meta parameter value

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform

Unfortunately terraform aws spotfleet resource configuration does not support the count meta parameter which means I can't use the count index value like it does here for aws_instance.

```
resource "aws_instance" "example" {
  count = 15
  ami = "ami-2d39803a"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"

  tags {
    Name = "example-${count.index}"
  }
}
```

Is it possible to configure resource similar above(and NOT create the resource) and only use it so I can use the count index from spotfleet resource?

```
# Request a Spot fleet
resource "aws_spot_fleet_request" "cheap_compute" {
  iam_fleet_role      = "arn:aws:iam::12345678:role/spot-fleet"
  spot_price          = "0.03"
  allocation_strategy = "diversified"
  target_capacity     = 6
  valid_until         = "2019-11-04T20:44:20Z"

  launch_specification {
    instance_type             = "m4.10xlarge"
    ami                       = "ami-1234"
    spot_price                = "2.793"

    tags {
      Name = "example-${aws_instance.example.count.index}"
    }
  }
}
```

I'm not sure in this is a good idea because terraform resource probably has a good reason why the count is not supported for spotfleet. However, I need to give unique tag value to each instance in the fleet.

Comment: Are you really sure that `aws_spot_fleet_request` does not support `count`?

Comment: @StephenKing, yes I'm positive. See here [link](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/spot_fleet_request.html) It supports target_capacity which has no count index.

Comment: I don't understand what your goal is. You can't access `count.index`, if you didn't specify a count for a resource. Do you want multiple spot fleet requests?

Comment: @StephenKing, my goal is that I want to create a phantom resource that supports count.index I will not be using so that I can refer to it from the spotfleet request resource and use that index value for the tag values. I want each ec2 instances to have unique tag value that ends with a value that increments by count.index value.

Comment: Ah, would say that's not possible from AWS side even..